# IE DOM namespace support for Ajax responseXML?

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, dom, namespaces

I have an entire JavaScript DOM/Ajax library I wrote from scratch back in 2005. It's been working fine with all major browsers. I just tested it with FF9 and Chrome 16. Back in 2005 it even worked with IE6. Now IE9 is doing screwy things.

My JavaScript talks to the server using Ajax. My server sends back XML with content type `text/xml`. My JavaScript looks at this XML DOM tree, returned in `responseXML`, and does stuff with it.

My response XML uses namespaces, so I use the standard DOM namespace-aware methods such as `Element.getAttributeNS()`. On IE9 this blows up with:

```
TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'getAttributeNS'
```

Sure enough, if I debug the JavaScript in IE9 using a breakpoint, I see that the available methods on responseXML do not include any of the namespace-aware DOM methods.

This is crazy, because my DOM code, before any Ajax stuff is done, checks the web page document to make sure that `getAttributeNS` is supported. Is it the case that IE9 supports namespaces on the web page document itself (which was served as `text/html`, not as `application/xhtml+xml` because, you guessed it, IE9 doesn't support that), but yet IE9 does not support namespaces on the Ajax `responseXML`, which was served as `text/xml`? What gives?

Is there some trick I need to pull to get IE9 to support namespace-aware methods on the `responseXML` DOM tree?

Comment: Try the [XSLT wrapper trick](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/2004/xhtml-faq#ie) to server the non-AJAX document as application/xml.